# Django: Validator returns False but form.is_valid() == True

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-2.0

I've created a custom validator which checks, if the upper number in `RangeField` is lower than some number.

The problem is that I can see in debug mode that the `Validator.compare` returns `False` but `Django` raises `DataError`

> Value "21474834555" is out of range for type integer LINE 1: ...NULL,
>   "cena" = NULL, "poznamka" = '', "rozloha" = '[ -214748...

I can't figure out why it raises this error when it should raise `ValidationError` before this.

I know that the number is out of range, that's why I've created the `Validator`.

**VIEW**

```
class DopytUpdateView(LoginRequiredMaklerAccessMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Dopyt
    form_class = DopytForm
    template_name = 'dopyty/dopyt.html'
```

**FORM**

```
class DopytForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Dopyt
        fields = [...'rozloha',...]
```

**VALIDATOR**

```
class RangeCompleteMaxValueValidator(MaxValueValidator):
    def compare(self, a, b):
        upper_ok = (a.upper > b) if a.upper else True
        lower_ok = (a.lower > b) if a.lower else True
        return upper_ok and lower_ok
```

**MODEL**

```
class Dopyt(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    rozloha = IntegerRangeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Rozloha [m2]',
                                validators=[RangeCompleteMinValueValidator(-2147483648),
                                            RangeCompleteMaxValueValidator(2147483647)])
```

Do you know why it behaves this way?

**EDIT**

As you can see, validator returns `False`

[image]

Comment: `a.upper` should probably be `a.upper()`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, it shouldn't, I've checked it. Moreover, I'm sure that validator returns False, check the bottom of the question, I've added a Pycharm Debug screenshot.

Comment: Aah... `a` and `b` aren't strings, these are ranges?

Comment: Yes, check the model: rozloha = IntegerRangeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Rozloha [m2]',
                                validators=[RangeCompleteMinValueValidator(-2147483648),
                                            RangeCompleteMaxValueValidator(2147483647)])

Answer (score 0):

**Form validator cant see models validators, you must use clean if you want to avoid to reach model layer**

You validador runs at your models instance, so when you going to save... while form.is_valid runs while in form, so this validations dont reach your models... to validate your logic at your form you should use clean

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
        subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

        if cc_myself and subject:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            if "help" not in subject:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Did not send for 'help' in the subject despite "
                    "CC'ing yourself."
                )
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/